# Can we obfuscate the identity?

Tags: clifford-group, quantum-advantage, solovay-kitaev-algorithm, compiling

Motivated by Aaronson's [call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4yiZcPthDI) to find simple, verifiable proofs of quantumness, suppose we start off with a random polynomial-length circuit $U$ of, say, Clifford+T gates, and attach $U^\dagger$ to it, can we then use a classical obfuscator to scramble $I=U^\dagger U$ beyond recognition, while still keeping the overall circuit size polynomial?

If we could do such scrambling easily enough, we can then provide a classical description of our obfuscated circuit for $I$, or alternatively of another random circuit $C$, to a quantum computer, who could determine which is which merely by executing the circuit on various basis states.

Indeed, we could insert a circuit such as $D=I+\epsilon$ that is exponentially close to the identity, and then run our circuit so obtained $U^\dagger D U$ through a Solovay-Kitaev compiler, to maybe add more spice to our circuit.

Are there enough known interesting relations to do such scrambling?  After all, non-identity-checking is coQMA-complete.

Comment: One option, which is not quite your question, is blind quantum computation, which has the ability to build in "trap qubits".

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know enough (or much at all) about blind quantum computing - I will study more!  Perhaps it seems dual to the above test for quantumness, though?  We aren't looking to bind a quantum algorithm to do our bidding and be oblivious about what that bidding is; rather, we wish for a quantum computer (and *only* a quantum computer) to recognize when it's been given the identity.